# Issue with Copyright header

Tags: sonarqube, licensing

How can I avoid to get a major issue "Copyright and license headers should be defined in all source files: Add or update the header of this file." By sonarQube analysys?
Can you post an example of valid Copyright header? 
I'm trying with a simple one:

```
/******************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2015 MyCompany
 * All right reserved
 ******************************************/
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The valid copyright header is defined in the rule activation in the profile in use. You don't mention which version of the platform you're using, so I'll assume a recent one. To see what the accepted header is:

1. check the project's Description widget to see which profile is applied for the language in question
2. go to the Rules page and search for the rule. Select it then right-arrow to see the rule detail page
3. at the bottom of the detail page is a list of profiles in which the rule is active, along with the parameter values in those profiles. Here's where you'll see the expected header.